# Are there animals that cannot feel pain?

Tags: zoology, pain

A thing I've often wondered is whether or not certain animals are immune to pain.

I've often read about Naked Mole Rats being unable to feel pain. Also I thought about other animals like Jellyfish who actually don't really have a brain and thus shouldn't have a reaction to pain.

So are there any animals or let's just say lifeforms that aren't immobile that are actually completely unable to feel pain?

Comment: Anything without nerves or sensory cells cannot "feel pain". For instance, sponges have neither.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you *hear or read*. This question appears to be *your own* speculation, and is off-topic. Please edit it to reference a claim that other people are making and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: @Oddthinking I apologize. I thought I'd just bring some personal thoughts to the topic with the jellyfish. I did however read about the mole rat in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_mole_rat) and other places.

Comment: I followed up to see if there was a simpler question: "Do naked mole rats feel no pain?" but Wikipedia and other sources make it clear that there are only certain types of pain-triggers that other mammals detect that Naked mole rats don't. Wikipedia provides a good reference to support the claim, so there is little to add.